# Can you have multiple forms to the same url on a page?

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc

I've got an MVC app that lists some products and I have a + and - graphic to increase/decrease the quantities. I surround these in form tags and have a couple of hidden fields one for the product id and one for the quantity. Both forms go to the same controller method. The only difference is the quantity 1 for increase -1 for decrease. The odd thing is the browser is only outputting 1 form field around the + (the second form on the page). Is it not possible to have the same form tag going to the same url on a page? I've even tried entering a unique id attribute, but to no avail.

As I type I've considered I could convert the graphic to an input of type image with the value as the quantity and wrap them both in the same post, not sure if that would work.

EDIT: to add code

```
<td style="text-align: right; width: 27px;">
            <% using (Html.BeginForm("Update", "Cart", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "form-remove" }))
               { %>
            <%= Html.Hidden("stockId", line.StockId)%>
            <%= Html.Hidden("quantity", -1)%>
            <%= Html.Hidden("returnUrl", ViewData["returnUrl"])%>
            <input type="image" class="icon icon-down" src="/Content/Images/spacer.gif" />
            <% } %>
        </td>
        <td style="text-align: right; width: 20px;">
            <% using (Html.BeginForm("Update", "Cart", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "form-add" } ))
               { %>
            <%= Html.Hidden("stockId", line.StockId)%>
            <%= Html.Hidden("quantity", 1)%>
            <%= Html.Hidden("returnUrl", ViewData["returnUrl"])%>
            <input type="image" class="icon icon-up" src="/Content/Images/spacer.gif" />
            <% } %>
        </td>
        <td style="text-align: right; width: 27px;">
            <% using (Html.BeginForm("Remove", "Cart"))
               { %>
            <%= Html.Hidden("stockId", line.StockId)%>
            <%= Html.Hidden("returnUrl", ViewData["returnUrl"])%>
            <input type="image" class="icon icon-remove" src="/Content/Images/spacer.gif" />
            <% } %>
        </td>
```

Above is an extract from my MVC view containing the icons. The update quantity by 1 renders but the -1 doesn't, even when adding the id attribute to the form. If I modify the action method to 'AddItem' and 'RemoveItem' instead of 'Update' it all renders fine, but then I'm almost duplicating my code with the only difference being the quantity parameter.

Comment: It should be possible. Can you post the relevant part of your view, and the signature of your controller method?

Comment: it should be possible. give two different names for the + and - button. then check whether + is called or - is called. Thats how i do in php. i don't know about asp.net

Comment: finally added my code - edited above.

Answer (score 0):

yes, you can have multiple forms on a page, here is a blog post on how to do it "[asp net mvc handling multiple form actions on one view](http://weblogs.asp.net/mikebosch/archive/2008/02/12/asp-net-mvc-handling-multiple-form-actions-on-one-view.aspx)" another option is to use an ajax request like this "[easy ajax with aspnet mvc and jquery](http://bob-the-janitor.blogspot.com/2010/12/easy-ajax-with-aspnet-mvc-and-jquery.html)"

Comment: Don't think you quite understood the question. I'm aware you can have multiple forms on the page but can you have multiple forms that POST to the SAME url. I'll add my code later tonight as an example, but two forms posting to the same url are currently only rendering 1 set of form tags around one of my icons regardless of me creating 2 distinct id tags on each form.

Comment: out of curiosity, why aren't use just doing it with ajax?

Comment: I need to make sure it degrades cleanly.

Comment: How do you get the right form to serialize with AJAX?  I have tried calling by the id

Comment: What dose your jQuery selector look like? my guess would be that's where the problem is